# Call Symfony console command within another command and suppress output

Tags: php, symfony, console-application

I have a simple console app using the Symfony console component.

I have two commands (say, `cmdOne` and `cmdTwo`) which can be called independently easily.

```
$ myApp.php cmdOne
$ myApp.php cmdTwo
```

Both commands have a considerable amount of output, which I can easily mute by issuing the `-q` option.

Now, I'd like `cmdOne` to call `cmdTwo` however I'd like `cmdTwo` to be quiet. I'm not trying to do anything crazy, but I'm struggling to get anywhere, despite reading through the docs.

Here's my sample code so far (this snippet would be contained within `cmdOne->execute()`):

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('cmdTwo');

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
    'command' => 'cmdTwo',
    '-q' => true
));

$returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

This runs fine, as in the code command executes, but there's output on the console (generated by `cmdTwo`) which I'd like to not show.

Is specifying the `-q` option not possible because it's "reserved" (i.e not created by the dev), or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of passing the same `$output` instance (the one that outputs to your current console) create an instance of `NullOutput`

```
$returnCode = $command->run($input, new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput);
```

It basically is a blackhole - it accepts output and silently drops it.

Comment: @cerebriform: it took 2 minutes more than it could due to phpstorm slow start time and reindexing a project (to find out the exact class name) ;-P

Comment: Awesome! That works a treat, thank you (and others); now here's a curve ball: If `cmdTwo` fails is there a sensible way to catch the output? At the moment, if run directly it just errors directly to the console - should I be returning a specific exit code for certain errors and then handling them in `cmdOne`? Or is this another SO question altogether...

Comment: But, but, I'm on a tablet with a greasy screen that's just not cooperating. :)

Comment: @HelloPablo: it depends. Is that command to be used separately? You can extend an `Output` abstract class and capture the whole output to a string.

Comment: @zerkms I'll rename `cmdOne` and `cmdTwo` to `install` and `migrate`. I want the `install` to execute `migrate` as part of it's process, but if `migrate` fails then I'd like `install` to fall over with errors on the console. `migrate` needs to be able to run on it's own as well. Clearer? Or clear as mud?

Comment: @HelloPablo extend `Output` class and capture the output.